# hey i have a problem in this clips expert system code its not printing the result

Tags: clips, expert-system

this is a Diet and Nutrition Expert System i have a problem that i cant print the result to the user after entering the input so can any one help me to make it run correctly?

```
(defrule read-gender
  (initial-fact)
  =>
  (printout t crlf crlf "Welcome! Diet and Nutrition Expert System" crlf)
  (printout t "******************************************" crlf)
  (printout t "This output of this program is:" crlf)
  (printout t "1. Your Body Mass Index (BMI) and body-status." crlf)
  (printout t "2. Recommended daily calories needed based on your body-status." crlf)
  (printout t "3. Daily protein needed based on your weight (kgs)." crlf)
  (printout t "4. Daily celcium needed based on your age." crlf)
  (printout t "5. Daily fiber needed based on your calories needed." crlf)
  (printout t "6. Daily carbohydrate needed based on your weight (kgs)." crlf)
  (printout t "******************************************" crlf crlf)
  (printout t "What is your gender (Female/Male) *case-sensitive*:") 
  (assert (gender (read))))
 
(defrule read-age
  (gender ?)
  =>
  (printout t "Please enter your age:")
  (assert (age (read))))

(defrule read-height
  (gender ?)
  =>
  (printout t "Please enter your height:")
  (assert (height (read))))

(defrule read-weight
  (gender ?)
  =>
  (printout t "Please enter your weight in(KGs):")
  (assert (weight (read))))

(defrule read-activity-days
  (gender ?)
  =>
  (printout t "How many day do you exercise for a week:")
  (assert (activity-days (read))))

(defrule set-activity-rate-sedentary
  (activity-days ?days)
  (test (< ?days 2))
  =>
  (assert (activity-rate "Sedentary"))
  (assert (activity-factor 1.2)))

(defrule set-activity-rate-moderate
  (activity-days ?days)
  (test (and (>= ?days 2) (< ?days 5)))
  =>
  (assert (activity-rate "Moderate"))
  (assert (activity-factor 1.55)))

(defrule set-activity-rate-hard
  (activity-days ?days)
  (test (>= ?days 5))
  =>
  (assert (activity-rate "Hard"))
  (assert (activity-factor 1.75)))

(defrule calculate-bmi
  (weight ?weight)
  (height ?height)
  =>
  (bind ?bmi (* ?weight (/ ?height ?height)))
  (assert (bmi ?bmi)))

(defrule set-body-status-underweight
  (bmi ?bmi)
  (test (< ?bmi 18.5))
  =>
  (assert (body-status "Underweight")))

(defrule set-body-status-normal-weight
  (bmi ?bmi)
  (test (and (>= ?bmi 18.5) (< ?bmi 24.9)))
  =>
  (assert (body-status "Normal-weight")))

(defrule set-body-status-overweight
  (bmi ?bmi)
  (test (and (>= ?bmi 24.9) (< ?bmi 29.9)))
  =>
  (assert (body-status "Overweight")))

(defrule calculate-daily-calories-female
  (gender "Female")
  (activity-factor ?activity-factor)
  (weight ?weight)
  (age ?age)
  (height ?height)
  =>
  (bind ?bmr (* 655.1 (+ (* 9.563 ?weight) (* 1.85 ?height) (* 4.676 ?age))))
  (bind ?daily-calories (* ?bmr ?activity-factor))
  (assert (daily-calories ?daily-calories)))

(defrule calculate-daily-calories-male
  (gender "Male")
  (activity-factor ?activity-factor)
  (weight ?weight)
  (age ?age)
  (height ?height)
  =>
  (bind ?bmr (* 66.5 (+ (* 13.75 ?weight) (* 5.003 ?height) (* 6.755 ?age))))
  (bind ?daily-calories (* ?bmr ?activity-factor))
  (assert (daily-calories ?daily-calories)))

(defrule set-daily-calcium-baby
  (age ?age)
  (test (< ?age 4))
  =>
  (assert (daily-calcium "210-270mg")))

(defrule set-daily-calcium-child
  (age ?age)
  (test (and (>= ?age 4) (< ?age 9)))
  =>
  (assert (daily-calcium "350-450mg")))

(defrule set-daily-calcium-teen
  (age ?age)
  (test (and (>= ?age 9) (< ?age 19)))
  =>
  (assert (daily-calcium "800mg")))

(defrule set-daily-calcium-adult
  (age ?age)
  (test (and (>= ?age 19) (< ?age 51)))
  =>
  (assert (daily-calcium "1000mg")))

(defrule set-daily-calcium-old
  (age ?age)
  (test (>= ?age 51))
  =>
  (assert (daily-calcium "1200mg")))

(defrule calculate-daily-protein-sedentary
  (weight ?weight)
  (activity-rate "Sedentary")
  =>
  (bind ?daily-protein (* ?weight 0.8))
  (assert (daily-protein ?daily-protein)))

(defrule calculate-daily-protein-moderate
  (weight ?weight)
  (activity-rate "Moderate")
  =>
  (bind ?daily-protein (* ?weight 1))
  (assert (daily-protein ?daily-protein)))

(defrule calculate-daily-protein-hard
  (weight ?weight)
  (activity-rate "Hard")
  =>
  (bind ?daily-protein (* ?weight 1.2))
  (assert (daily-protein ?daily-protein)))


(defrule calculate-daily-carbohydrates
  (weight ?weight)
  =>
  (bind ?daily-carbohydrates (* ?weight 2.5))
  (assert (daily-carbohydrates ?daily-carbohydrates)))


(defrule protein-advice
(protein-needed ?p)
=>
(printout t crlf crlf"      ########   Result  ######## " crlf)
(printout t "       1. You need " ?p "g of protein per day." crlf))

(defrule carbohydrate-advice
(carbohydrate-needed ?c)
=>
(printout t "       3. You need " ?c "g of carbohydrate per day." crlf))

(defrule fiber-advice
(fiber-needed ?f)
=>
(printout t "       2. You need " ?f "g of fiber per day." crlf))

(defrule calcium-advice
(calcium-needed ?c)
=>
(printout t "       4. You need " ?c "g of calcium per day." crlf))

(defrule calories-advice-underweight
(body-status underweight)
(calories-needed ?c)
(bmi ?bm)
(body-status ?b)
(carbohydrate-needed ?ca)
(calcium-needed ?ce)
=>
(printout t "
5. Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is " ?bm " (" ?b "), "crlf "
6. You
need " ?c " calories per day. "crlf "
7. For advice from the experts, You may need extra
daily 300 calories (" (+ 300 ?c)") to gain 0.25kg/week." crlf crlf))
 
(defrule calories-advice-normalweight
(body-status normal-weight)
(calories-needed ?c)
(bmi ?bm)
(body-status ?b)
(carbohydrate-needed ?ca)
(calcium-needed ?ce)
=>
(printout t "       5. Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is " ?bm " (" ?b ")," crlf "  6. You
need " ?c " calories per day to maintain your healthy weight." crlf crlf))


(defrule calories-advice-overweight
   (body-status overweight)
   (calories-needed ?c)
   (bmi ?bm)
   (body-status ?b)
   (carbohydrate-needed ?ca)
   (calcium-needed ?ce)
   =>
   (printout t "        5. Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is " ?bm " (" ?b ")," crlf "  6. You need " ?c " calories per day. " crlf "       7. For advice from the experts, You may need to reduce your daily calories needed by 300 to " (- ?c 300)))

(defrule calories-advice-obesity
(body-status obesity)
(calories-needed ?c)
(bmi ?bm)
(body-status ?b)
(carbohydrate-needed ?ca)
(calcium-needed ?ce)
=>
(printout t "       5. Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is " ?bm " (" ?b "), "crlf "  6. You
need " ?c " calories per day. "crlf "       7. For advice from the experts, You may need to reduce
your daily calories needed by 500 to (" (- ?c 300)") to loss 0.5kg/week." crlf crlf))
```

I tried to rewrite the code in different ways but its still working correctly but without any result so can any one please help me to rewrite it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use an initial-fact pattern in your rules. The initial-fact is
   no longer supported in CLIPS 6.4. Just leave the conditions of the
   rule empty and it will work in both version 6.3 and 6.4.
2. The protein-advice defrule expects a protein-needed fact but a
   daily-protein fact is asserted by your other rules.
3. The carbohydrate-advice defrule expects a carbohydrate-needed fact but a daily-carbohydrates fact is asserted by your other rules.
4. The fiber-advice defrule expects a fiber-needed fact but no fiber
   related facts are asserted by any of your rules.
5. The calcium-advice defrule expects a calcium-needed fact but a daily-calcium fact is asserted by your other rules.
6. Your other rules that print results have similar issues.